# Add custom converter before manully binding properties using EnvironmentAware : Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, google-secret-manager, spring-cloud-gcp

I need to dynamically add beans to my application for which I need to bind some properties from application.yml (some properties depend on gcp secret manager)

Below is the custom binding and bean registration.

```java
@Component
public class PropertiesRegistrar implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware {

private ConfigProperties configProperties

@Override
  public void setEnvironment(@NotNull Environment environment) {
    configProperties = Binder.get(environment)
        .bind("custom-props", ConfigProperties.class)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidConfigurationException("No config properties found"));
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(@NotNull BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
// register some custom beans here using configProperties
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(@NotNull ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    // no post-process steps required
  }
}
```

ConfigProperties.java

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("custom-props")
public class ConfigProperties {

  private String url;
  private String user;
  private String password;

}
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import: "sm://"
  cloud:
    gcp:
      project-id: my-project
      secretmanager:
        enabled: true
        project-id: my-project

custom-props:
  url: myurl
  user: ${sm://user-key}
  password: ${sm://user-password}
```

If you look at `application.yml` I am trying to fetch secrets from gcp (it is able to get secrets) but since I implement `EnvironmentAware` (in PropertiesRegistrar) to bind my properties which is invoked very early in the startup, Binder is unable to convert secrets (`user` and `password` fields in properties) that are in `com.google.protobuf.ByteString` to `String` , due to which I am facing errors. I tried registering custom `Converter<S, T>` but they are of no use, since this binding happens too early during context buildup.

Now I want to know if there is a proper way to achieve this conversion (secrets conversion from ByteString to String ) at the time of above properties binding?